# Using context value in a Node-RED switch node

Tags: javascript, node-red, jsonata

I'm using the Switch node in Node-RED to determine if I should batch upload a buffered array *(which is stored in a context object)*.

I would like the property to be `flow.batchData.length`, and the condition to be`>= 100`.

If I select the property type to be `flow.`, and set the property value to be `batchData`, I can't then access the `length` attribute of the array.

I tried using a Javascript expression property type, but the following value didn't work: `flow.get("batchData").length`.

How can I use the length of an object stored in context in a Switch node?

---

Exported Node here:

```
[{"id":"de5265d5.0f7408","type":"switch","z":"157e7444.ffccac","name":"Should upload?","property":"flow.get(\"batchData\").length","propertyType":"jsonata","rules":[{"t":"gte","v":"100","vt":"num"}],"checkall":"true","repair":false,"outputs":1,"x":820,"y":620,"wires":[["410db161.d497b"]]}]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The JSONata expression to be used to count the amount of elements in the array stored in your `flow` context  variable should be:

`$count($flowContext("batchData"))`

and the configuration dialog of your switch node will look like:

[image]

Comment: Thanks. I presumed it was a generic Javascript expression box, not JSONata.